# Tabular 3 level header

Tags: tables

How can I draw a tabular like below using the given script.

[image: below]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{}c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{TOP.1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{TOP.2} \\
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
    \cline{3-8}
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{}c|}{} & TOP.1.1 & TOP.1.2 & TOP.1.3 & TOP.2.1 & TOP.2.2 & TOP.2.3\\
    \hline

    \multirow{3}{*}{SIDE.1}
    & SIDE.1.1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8}
    & SIDE.1.2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8}
    & SIDE.1.3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8}
    \hline

    \multirow{3}{*}{SIDE.2}
    & SIDE.2.1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8}
    & SIDE.2.2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8}
    & SIDE.2.3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{2-8}
    \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        \cline{4-9}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{TOPS} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{\begin{sideways}SIDES\end{sideways}}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{TOP.1} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{TOP.2} \\ \cline{4-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TOP1.1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TOP1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TOP1.3} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TOP2.1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{TOP2.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{TOP2.3} \\ \cline{2-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{SIDE.1}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SIDE1.1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} \\ \cline{3-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SIDE1.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} \\ \cline{3-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SIDE1.3} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} \\ \cline{2-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{SIDE.2}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SIDE2.1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} \\ \cline{3-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SIDE2.2} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} \\ \cline{3-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{SIDE2.3} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

resulting in:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a possible solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

%\begin{figure}
        \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc|*{6}{c|}}   \cline{4-9}
                                  & &                                     &\multicolumn{6}{c|}{Tops}\\ \hline
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=cc]{270}{Slides} }  } &   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{TOP.1} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{TOP.2} \\
    \arrayrulecolor{black}    \cline{4-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}    &   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & TOP.1.1 & TOP.1.2 & TOP.1.3 & TOP.2.1 & TOP.2.2 & TOP.2.3\\
    \cline{2-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}    &   \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{SIDE.1}}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{SIDE.1.1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}    &  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}&  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{SIDE.1.2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}    &  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{SIDE.1.3} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-9}    \cline{2-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}     &  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{SIDE.2}}    &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{SIDE.2.1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}     & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{SIDE.2.2} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}     & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{SIDE.2.3} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cline{3-9}    \hline
  \end{tabular}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```